# Python version in Programs and Features is different to that in Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

I have Windows 10 Home 64-bit. In the Control Panel > Programs and Features menu, I can see that I have Python 3.5.2 (Anaconda 4.1.1 64-bit) installed. As I wanted to upgrade Python 3.5 to Python 3.6, I then ran this command in Anaconda Prompt `conda install python=3.6.8`. After the upgrading/installing process in Anaconda Prompt was finished, I ran this command `python -V` and it showed `Python 3.6.8 :: Anaconda 4.1.1 (64-bit)`. However, when I refreshed the Control Panel > Programs and Features menu, it still showed Python 3.5.2 (Anaconda 4.1.1 64-bit). I then ran this command `conda info --envs` and it showed I only have the base environment.

Could anyone please advise:

1. Why are there two different information of Python versions in this case?
2. Which Python version is actually installed in my laptop?
3. In my Jupyter Lab Launcher, under Notebook section, I can see two Python symbols: Python 3 and Python [conda env:root]*. What are the differences between these two and which one should I use to launch a new notebook?

Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

1. Conda creates virtual environment inside your machine. The python version is different inside conda. If you want install different python inside conda you can decide the python at the time of creation of environment.

   conda create -n TestEnv python=3.6.8

   2. If you want update the python inside conda virtual environment, activate the virtual environment using

   conda activate TestEnv

   3. Now you can see the python version of your virtual environment
   4. Deactivate your virtual environment and check python version using `python -V` this is the version of your Laptop Python or base version of python.

Comment: Hi Lokesh, thanks for your input. I'm aware of creating virtual environments for different Python versions. But as I'm a novice to Python, I just want to have the base environment with 3.6.8, which I already achieved. However, the different information of Python version between Control Panel and Anaconda confused me and I'm not sure what the implications would be.